# QTimer running in QThread

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, qtimer

I need a class with a timer which will do a task every 100msec, this class need to run in a thread, so I would like to combine qtimer with qthread.

I have created the following code:

```
class Worker : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
    void setEnabled(bool enable);
    
    public slots:
    void initialize();
    
    private:
    void doWork();
    
    QTimer *m_timer;
}

void Worker::initialize()
{
    m_timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, &Worker::doWork, Qt::DirectConnection);
    m_timer->start(100);
}

void Worker::setEnabled(bool enable)
{
    if(enable)
        m_timer->start(100);
    else
        m_timer->stop();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication app(argc,argv);

    QThread *thread = new QThread;
    Worker *worker = new Worker;
    
    QObject::connect(thread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::initialize);
    
    worker->moveToThread(thread);
    thread->start();
    
    app.exec();

    delete worker;
    delete thread;
}
```

With the following commands I could then enable/disable the time

worker->setEnabled(false);
worker->setEnabled(true);

I have tested and it works fine, but I would like to know if this is the correct way?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @JarMan I see several errors (perhaps caused by not providing a [mre]), I do not see any QXApplication, calling setEnabled synchronously does a segmented fault since the memory of m_timer is not separated until after calling initialize which clearly does not know does in your code, invoke an object that belongs to a new thread from the main thread, memory leaks, etc.

Comment: Ok, I was just doing a quick eyeball because the OP said "it works fine".

Comment: `QThread *thread = new QThread;
    Worker *worker = new Worker;` - You are leaking these objects.

Comment: You are right, the worker->setEnabled(false) & worker->setEnabled(true) where not ment to be inside the code block. It was more of a question if this was a correct way of disable /enablde the timer. I have edit the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not entirely correct.

`Worker::setEnabled(bool enable)` should be a slot too, as it's invoking the `QTimer::start()` slot directly. Calling `Worker::setEnabled` directly from the main thread then results in undefined behavior. You must use a signal-slot connection to invoke `setEnabled` safely from the main thread.

You also should have initialized `Worker::m_timer` in the constructor rather than deferring it until `initialize()`, so you don't run into a dangling pointer if `Worker::setEnabled` was invoked earlier than expected. `moveToThread` will move all children of `Worker` with it, so that's perfectly sane behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I need to mention is that the m_timer can't be initialzed in the constructor. See here information from qt:

*By the way, one extremely important thing to note here is that you should NEVER allocate heap objects (using new) in the constructor of the QObject class as this allocation is then performed on the main thread and not on the new QThread instance, meaning that the newly created object is then owned by the main thread and not the QThread instance. This will make your code fail to work. Instead, allocate such resources in the main function slot such as initialize() in this case as when that is called the object will be on the new thread instance and thus it will own the resource.*

Comment: That only applies for `QObject` created without a parent. When specifying a parent such as in this case, thread affinity follows the parent when it's moved.